# Count number of distinct values in the same position in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

Consider the following list:

```
l=[[{'a': 'a'}, {'a': 'b'}, {'a': 1}], [{'a': 'a'}, {'a': 'b'}, {'a': 1}], [{'a': 'a'}, {'a': 'c'}, {'a': 1}]]
```

I would like to find the number of distinct elements on a same position in this list.

Example

- if position=1, output would be 2 ( `{'a': 'b'}` and `{'a': 'c'}`).
- if position=0, output would be 1: ( `{'a': 'a'}` and `{'a': 'c'}`).

Is there a way to do this using map/lambda ? I dont want to do a loop for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```py
len(set(map(lambda x: tuple(x[position].items()), l)))
```

Although I'd recommend never use such code IRL.

Comment: This works. Thank you. Can you tell me why shouldnt I use such code ?

Comment: BTW, An upvote and accepting the answer would be better than a thank you :)

Comment: Both is better ;D it is not yet possible. In 2 minutes